# Git hooks in PHPStorm on Mac

Tags: macos, git, bash, phpstorm, githooks

I've got problem with commiting in PHPStorm with `pre-commit` hook enabled.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

# Message
message () {
    if [ $2 -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "${1}: Error"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "${1}: Success"
    fi
}

# JSHint
grunt lint:js &> /dev/null
message "JSHint" $?

# Unit tests
grunt test:unit:frontend &> /dev/null
message "Unit tests" $?
```

Code is pretty simple, it just fire Grunt tasks one by one and show short message for commit that it failed or not.

The problem is that when I run it in terminal - it works correctly, when I try to run it in PHPStorm I get information `grunt: command not found`.

It occurs only on Mac, as I tried on Ubuntu and it works. Also I tested which user is running this script with `whoami` and it's the same user which is logged in.

Do you have any ideas what's wrong, or maybe someone just had same issue?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Instead of just `grunt` try using full path. Most likely process that executes this does not see full PATH env variable (for whatever reason). See if launching PhpStorm from terminal via `open  -a /Applications/PhpStorm.app/` will do any better.

Comment: Launching by terminal didn't changed anything, when I tried to run grunt via full path, I get error `env: node: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Do you use `nvm` or alike? No other *real* ideas, sorry.

Comment: No, I installed NodeJS directly from official page. Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IDEA-134108](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134108) is fixed, fix should be available in next PHPStorm release